# How to print email verification URL from Firebase Auth in Emulator?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am using the Firebase Emulator for local testing. I have a signupUser Firebase Function that uses Firebase Auth to sign up users (and does some extra work). Both of them use the Emulator, and the issue is, this way the email verification URL does not get printed neither to the console (in which I run the Emulator) nor to the Functions Log. As a result, I cannot verify my new test users and cannot log in. Is there any other way to verify these test users' email addresses or to manually print the verification URL?

Comment: Do you need to create a new user every time?

Comment: At this point not necessarily. Later on it would be nice though, for e2e tests around the sign up flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found it. Using the Admin SDK we can generate a verification link, that we can then console log.

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(useremail, actionCodeSettings)
```

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link

Comment: you also must have on the client library this option as well, its on the client object, at least in flutter we have it, so I don't need to add any new key to use admin sdk:

```
UserCredential userCredential = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
email: "user@email.com", password: r'A$1234567890',);
await userCredential.user?.sendEmailVerification(); 

```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, more automated, so you don't need to add the admin sdk:

Here is the auth log output for a new user within the Emulator:
[image: Emulator Auth Log]

Then base on [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-auth-emulator-oob) you can fetch the oobCodes (out of band
codes) with restAPI:

[image]

Also documentation described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#emulated_email_email_link_and_anonymous_authentication)